# is it safe and good practice to use third party libraries for React Native UI?

Tags: android, reactjs, user-interface, mobile, native

I am new in React Native. I am making hands on demos to learn react native.
I go through basic components and style. Facebook is not provieing all rich component for making rich UI. But many third party library like [react elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements) and [native base](https://nativebase.io/) provides many rich UI componants. So my concern is that is it safe to use those controls? are they can conflict with inbuilt control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe?  How much do you trust the authors.  I would not include a library that isn't a well known open source library or from a major corporation you trust without reading every line of it to check for malware.

Conflicts won't be a problem.  Its not like any of them replace other Components.  How well they work will vary from library to library, of course.

Edit:  A warning I just thought to add-  do not assume a React library will work in ReactNative.  React libraries tend to embedd HTML in the render() function, that doesn't work in ReactNative and will cause crashes/red screens of death.